# Can I reward people in-kind for donating to a political party (or candidate) of my choosing?

Tags: constitutional-law, property, voting

Suppose I would like to reward people who contributed to a political leader in the past year. I intend to give those donors private property, influence, or other compensation.

This would occur after the campaign has ended, and the donors have no knowledge that this reward system would occur.   (not sure if this matters)

---

**Question**

- Is soliciting this information, and rewarding them legal?
- What steps can I take to ensure I'm not running afoul of FEC laws?
- Would any aspect of this reward system be considered a PAC, or can it be construed as exceeding an individual maximum contribution?
  (e.g. the maximum donation by individuals is $2,500, but Citizens United allows for greater contributions by corporations)

What I don't want to do is to be considered coercive, or bribing an individual, on a legal, or ethical level.  My goal is to kick start a community project among likeminded peers.

Comment: This information is mostly already available. http://www.fec.gov/pages/brochures/citizens.shtml All contributors who gave more than $200 in a calendar year to a committee must be identified publicly. You want to give rewards to people who gave *less* than $200 and can prove to you that they did?

Comment: I assume you are interested in federal elections, not state and lower.

Comment: To keep this simple, let's focus on >$200 ... @dawn

Comment: Citizens United does not allow for greater contributions by corporations. It allows for unlimited *independent* expenditures. It is illegal for a corporation or union to contribute directly to a federal campaign.

Comment: @Dawn What type of lawyer would I need to have a deeper discussion of Citizens United/FEC, and a business that I create that gives independent expenditures to citizens in return for donations?

Comment: Are you referring to this?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_money